# ListView height to wrap it arraylist size in android

Tags: android, listview

How can i set listview height matched to arraylist size. for Example if my arraylist content is 15 items height of listview height should wrap that 15 items it its 5 item then it should wrap to 5 items.

````
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/choices_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_txt"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>```
````

Answer (score 0):

use height of listview `wrap_content` instead of 150dp